# Passing Dynamic Data to Power BI Embedded

Tags: javascript, json, powerbi-embedded

I would like to use Power BI Embedded in my Web App. My web app allows users to design their own data structures and collect data into them (more like google forms). This means
- I am dealing with dynamic json data

Can powerBI api help me do either of the following
- Push my json data to the Power BI embedded and let the user create their own tiles and reports on Power BI.
- Or i can parse through the json and generate Graphs on Power BI based on the datatypes in the JSON

Any ideas, code snippets, links will be great.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can use JSON as a data source and it would work with either Desktop or Embeded reports if you did a GenerateTokenRequest with EDIT permission. See this technet article from Microsoft https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38138.generate-power-bi-reports-from-data-in-json-file.aspx